# Dns.GetHostEntry returns different addresses on two different computers

Tags: c#, networking, dns, mono, ip-address

When I try to resolve a specific domain name on my computer using `Dns.GetHostEntry` it returns an IP address (only one address in `AddressList`), but when I run the same line of code on my server which is on the same network, it returns a completely different address.

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDUFa.jpg) a screenshot that sums it up.

Unfortunately I can't disclose the actual domain names, but the two strings (example.domain.com) are exactly identical.

I used mono and C# interactive for the sake of easier demonstration, the same happens when I run an actual program.

The `hosts` file is intact on both computers, so it can't interfere with the ip lookup.

So here's my question: Why are the two computers returning two different ip addresses for the same domain name? How can I force the program to return only one address / a list containing all addresses that domain name points to?

Comment: Are you sure C# has anything to do with this? What does `nslookup` for the hostname give you on the 2 different computers?

Comment: Same as C#, it gives me different ip addresses

Comment: Both machines are using the same DNS server? You cleared the DNS cache on both machines?

Comment: Either they are using different DNS servers, or the single dns server has multiple IP entries for that host name, etc....

Comment: Alright, this is getting weirder. On windows, `nslookup example.domain.com` returns a different address every time I run it. It alternates between two addresses.

Comment: @LázárZsolt The dns server(s) has multiple entries and is round-robining the entries...

Comment: Is there a way to return all ip addresses that point to that domain in C#?

Comment: This still doesn't explain why one computer only finds 1 of 3 addresses, while the other computer only finds the remaining two.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to get Ipv4 ("192.168.1.22"):

```
public static string GetLocalIPAddress()
{
    var host = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName());
    foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
    {
        if (ip.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        {
           return ip.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the way to get Ipv4 ("192.168.1.22") like this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).